# Runnable jar, pass in argument to file in the jar

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a runnable jar, and inside I have the following packaged:

```
myfolder1-
        -myfile1
        -myfile2
```

Inside my jar I am running the following code:

```
String filename = args[0];
...
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

How can I reference these files on the commandline? If I explode the jar I see them there (myfolder1 in same directory as the location I unzipped from)

I have tried

```
java -jar myjar.jar classpath:myfolder1/myfile1
java -jar myjar.jar myfolder1/myfile1
```

to no avail

Answer (score 0):

java -jar myjar.jar ./myfolder1/myfile1

So try to add the "./" or the complete path before the folder and tell me if it works.

Comment: Is there spaces in the path or name?

Comment: BTW, Scanner object can take the file path directly, there is no need for "new File", try removing it.

Comment: Did you include the file' extensions, e.g. ".txt" that might be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

with filepath being args[0]

Thanks all!